# Change font and size, CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying with HTML and CSS, have the program read a text file and write it on top of an image, I managed to read the file, but I can not find a way to change the font, the size of the letter, among other things.

Here is all the code.

```css
<style type="text/css">
 @font-face {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  src: url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700) format("truetype");
 }
 p.montserrat { 
  font-family: "Montserrat", Verdana, Tahoma;
 }
</style>

<p style="overflow: hidden; float: left;">

 <img style="margin: 0px 0px -74px 0px;" src="NewOverlay.png" />
 <div style="position: absolute; top: 95px; left: 60px;">
  <object type="text/plain" data="sub.txt" width="400" height="300"></object>
 </div>
</p>
```

Comment: You included `javascript` as your tag yet I don't see any javascript here.

Comment: There is no JavaScript included in this question.  Why are you using an `<object>`?  Why do you not have a `font-size` CSS attribute?

Comment: Also, a `div` cannot be inside a `p`.

Answer (score 1):

Hi if you are looking for a way to just change the size. This might be a solution, this will change the font size, and make it scale. Depending on the the monitor.

```
<style type="text/css">
        @font-face {
            font-family: "Montserrat";
            src: url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700) 
    format("truetype");
        }
        p.montserrat { 
            font-family: "Montserrat", Verdana, Tahoma;
            font-size: 2vw; 
/* This will make the font scale to 2% of width of the monitor.
    You can also specify a second value: font-size: 2vh; 
     That would make it scale to the height of the monitor too
      You could also tinker a bit with them together seperated by,
       a comma.*/
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help, I need to change the size and the letter of the "sub.txt" file. I don't know if this code can be useful. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Try adding the code under the `<div>`. Also you can't have a `<div>` under a paragraph ( `<p>` ). switch them around.

Answer (score 0):

Your css selector is specifying the `<p>` needs the class 'montserrat'. You'll need `<p class="montserrat">` for it to work correctly (or update the selector to just `p` - removing the `.montserrat`). I've also updated the markup below to change the `<div>` to a `<span>` for validity.

```
<p class="montserrat" style="overflow: hidden; float: left;">
   <img style="margin: 0px 0px -74px 0px;" src="NewOverlay.png" />
   <span style="position: absolute; top: 95px; left: 60px;">
      <object type="text/plain" data="sub.txt" width="400" height="300"></object>
   </span>
</p>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help, I tried to do this but it still does not change the size of the letters, or the font.